# Rails Paperclip S3 signed URL not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

A couple months ago I set up a rails app. Uploaded picture were saved in a private bucket on S3. I could download them through an expiring URL. Now that is not working anymore, even though I did not change anything. What could be the reason? A timezone issue?

My generated Link looks like this: 
http:// [bucket] .s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com//original/image.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId= [AQCCESS_KEY] \u0026Expires=1408020974\u0026Signature= [signature]

With this linked I tried to download a file at 10.56 am central european time on August 10th. Might there be a time zone issue? How to I read the Expires parameter in that URL.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This answers your - 'How to I read the Expires parameter in that URL.?' question:

The Expires time is defined as [Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). In order to see what that time is, you can run the following ruby code:

```
require 'date'    
DateTime.strptime("1408020974",'%s').to_s
```

which returns this:

```
"2014-08-14T12:56:14+00:00"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!
The good news is: I know how to read the date and there doesn't seem to be a problem with the expiring time.
The bad news: The problem must be somewhere else. But I dont see what else could be wrong. Something in the creation process of the signed URL must be wrong. I check the AWS key and the secret key. They are both correct. Is there a way to generate a signed URL easily so that I can check for possible errors?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem:

As I said, the link looks like this:

> http:// [bucket] .s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com//original/image.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId= [AQCCESS_KEY] \u0026Expires=1408020974\u0026Signature= [signature]

The problem is the **u0026** which has to be replaced by  "**&**"-sign. I will think about how to solve the problem. But at least it is identified :)